# crash in NSFileCoordinator moving item to another url in Snow Leopard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I have used the `NSFileCoordinator` object to move a file from one location to another as under. I am executing this inside a block using `dispatch_async` API.

```
NSFileCoordinator* coordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] init];

NSString* srcPath = @"some path";
NSString* destPath = @"dest path";

NSURL* srcLocation = [NSURL urlWithPath:srcPath];
NSURL* destLocation = [NSURL urlWithPath:destPath];

[coordinator itemAtURL:srcLocation willMoveToURL:destLocation];
```

**My deployment target is 10.7.**

When I run the application in 10.9 there is no error and moves the file to destination location. But, if I run the same app in 10.7. It gives below exception as:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSFileCoordinator
>   itemAtURL:willMoveToURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7f7f921c3d70'

What could be the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the method is available ins in OS X v10.8 and later.You can not use it in 10.7.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Oops! I should have checked method documentation.